# React.js: Cancel button is cancelling editing but leaving the state with the changed value after editing was started

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state, conditional-rendering

In my form, by default I display data from state with Edit button beside it. When Edit is clicked, an inline form appears in place of the data along with a Save and a Cancel button. When Save is pressed, state is updated. But when Cancel is pressed, the input field should disappear and the previous state value appears.

I have implemented this far. But, after editing the text in the input field if I click Cancel, the input field is going away but the edited text is showing where the non-edited previous text should appear.

Before editing:---

[image: before editing]

During Editing:---

[image: during editing]

After clicking cancel:---
[image: after clicking cancel]

After clicking Cancel, the value should be IT Service, but it's showing the edited value which should have been discarded!

How do I show the previous value after clicking Cancel?

My code:

```
const [ edit, setEdit ] = useState(false);
const [ cancelEdit, setCancelEdit ] = useState(false);
const [ myJob, setMyJob ] = useState('IT Service')
const [ showJob, setShowJob ] = useState('');
const [ saved, setSaved ] = useState(false);

const isEdit = edit;

const handleCancelEdit = () => {
    setCancelEdit(!cancelEdit);
    setEdit(!edit);
};

const handleSave = () => {
    setSaved(!saved);
    setEdit(!edit);
    setShowJob(myJob);
}
return (
    <div>
        <p> Job: 
            <span>
                { !isEdit ? (<span>{ myJob} <button type="submit" onClick={e=>setEdit(!edit)}>Edit</button></span>) :
                (
                    <span>
                        <input type="text" name="myJob" value={myJob}
                            onChange={e=>setMyJob(e.target.value)} />
                        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSave}>Save</button>
                        <button type="submit" onClick={handleCancelEdit}>Cancel</button>
                    </span>
                )}  
            </span>
        </p>
        <h4>Present job: <em>{showJob}</em></h4>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You didnt reset the input value.

```
    const handleCancelEdit = () => {
    setCancelEdit(!cancelEdit);
    setEdit(!edit);
    setMyJob(showJob)
};
```

Comment: For testing purpose only I have used this showJob state. So, how do I do it when I have removed this showJob?

Answer (score 0):

Came out with a solution using `useRef`:

```
const presentJob = useRef(myJob);

const handleCancelEdit = () => {
    setCancelEdit(!cancelEdit);
    setEdit(!edit);
    setMyJob(presentJob.current);
};

const handleSave = () => {
    setSaved(!saved);
    setEdit(!edit);
    setShowJob(myJob);
    presentJob.current = myJob;
};
```